# Centralized configuration variables for jenkinspipe jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am a newbie to jenkins pipeline. I am looking to develop a shared library which can load configuration variables from database or external resource via Restful interface, then all variables will be ingested into each jenkins pipeline jobs.

Any advice for best practices to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be with [workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin).
You could write the groovy code fetching the parameters there, and then use those from any pipeline you'd like.